# Filtering combobox by other combobox

Tags: c#, winforms

when I want a combobox With combobox The other filter I do this message to my shows 
Non-static method requires a target

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do it is to have a database table for each combobox's values linked by foreign keys. Then when the selection is made, query the other table based on the id of combox value.

Comment: Two comboboxs is connected to database by entity framework